# post__in for get_posts with a dynamic array

Tags: posts, wp-query, wpdb

I am creating an RSS feed. I have created a table in my database with 400 post id's. I have the rss feed coded I am now trying to link the two so my RSS feed runs only for the list  of 400 posts from my table.

On my RSS feed page I can create an array by using a couple of id's (see below)

```
$myarray2 = array(12345,12346);
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'posttype',
'post__in' => $myarray2
);
```

This works and creates an RSS feed for id's 12345,12346.

I can also print the array of my 400 database table records on the page as follows;

```
$myarray = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM my_table");
print_r($myarray)
```

This produces data of this form

```
( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                [id] => 145 
            ) 
        [1] => stdClass Object ( 
                [id] => 4573 
            ) 
        [2] => continues.....
)
```

However I can not seem to get the code right to use `$myarray` with `post__in` for example

```
$myarray = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM my_table");
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'posttype',
'post__in' => $myarray
);
```

does not work. I have tried various variations but I am missing something about how to deliver a list of post id's from my array to `post__in`

What am I missing?

Comment: `$myarray` in the last case is not an simple array with post ids , it's an array of rows resulted from sql query. So loop through that result and get ids into an array.

Comment: I have tried to do that but I can't seem to get the syntax correct. Do you have any pointers about how to do it.=?

Answer (score 1):

`post__in` accept array of post IDs e.g. `array(5, 4, 8, 9);`

Extending @bravokeyl comment. By default result is Object. As codex suggest you can change the output type of [`get_results()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results) to these values.

> - OBJECT - result will be output as a numerically indexed array of row objects.
> - OBJECT_K - result will be output as an associative array of row objects, using first column's values as keys (duplicates will be
>     discarded).
> - ARRAY_A - result will be output as a numerically indexed array of associative arrays, using column names as keys.
> - ARRAY_N - result will be output as a numerically indexed array of numerically indexed arrays.

Here we can change output to `ARRAY_A` then extract post IDs and pass to `post__in`

```
global $wpdb;
$fivesdrafts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM my_table", ARRAY_A);
$post_ids = array_map(function($single_array){
    return $single_array['ID'];
}, $fivesdrafts);

//Pass this to post__in
array(
    'post__in' => $post_ids
);
```

Comment: Thanks - however when I use that code structure I get this error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: You did not read my answer well :P You need to change the output type to `ARRAY_A` in `get_results`

Comment: Using this global 
    $wpdb;
   $jlk = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM my_table ARRAY_A");
   $jlk2 = array_map( function($post) {
            return $post->ID;
        }, $jlk );


    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_post',
    'numberposts' => 10,
    'post__in'=> $jlk2
     );
    $results = get_posts($args);

I don't get an error, I can print the array which looks like this
(( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 14578 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 14573 ) )

but it does notwork in this location  'post__in'=> $jlk2

Comment: No! Function accept 2nd argument, separated by comma. See the example above. It just copy paste. `("SELECT * FROM en_notsold", ARRAY_A)` and `return $post['ID']`

Comment: OK I'm getting closer, 

global $wpdb;
$jlk = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM my_table", ARRAY_A);

$jlk2 = array_map( function($post) {
            return $post->ID;
        }, $jlk );


$args = array(
'post_type' => 'custompost',
'numberposts' => 401,
'post__in'=> $jlk2
);
$result = get_posts($args);

if I print_r the $jlk2 the id is missing, I only see the index (Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => etc ) so I need to see the post_id column.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way by using `wpdb::get_col()` and fetch the `id` column:

```
$pids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT id FROM my_table" );
```

We could then clean it by integer convert each id with:

```
$pids = wp_parse_id_list( $pids );
```

[Just note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) the different max value for `intval()`, depending on 32 or 64 bits systems.

Answer (score -2):

OK I got it to work as follows.

```
global $wpdb;
$jlk = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM my_table");

foreach($jlk as $custompost) {
 $custompost_ids[] = $custompost->ID;
}

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'custompost',
'numberposts' => -1,
'post__in'=> $custompost_ids
);
$result = get_posts($args);
```

Comment: Why are you fetching the whole table if you only need the ID column ? Looks like you could simplify more with`wpdb::get_col()` since it's made for selecting a single column and returns a single dimensional array.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I need to make an edit here!

Comment: There is only one column in the table.